# Large CSS vs Large HTML

Tags: html, optimization, css, less

Is it better to limit the HTML to few classes and ids and keep the size of the HTML low OR is it better to use a lot of nested CSS instead.

These are the advantages I can think of for both.

Advantages of using few nested CSS rules:

- Smaller CSS file
- Efficient targeting of elements inside the CSS
- Possibly quicker rendering times in the CSS (not sure about this)

Advantages of using a lot of nested CSS rules:

- Small HTML size throughout the site
- CSS gets cached
- Better organization of code (I'm using LESS)

Thanks.

Comment: If your CSS isn't cached by browsers, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in the question. I meant the HTML doesn't get cached.

Comment: It depends if performance is important.. do you have JavaScript that alters the dom Constantly? if so then smaller CSS will be more performant for that. otherwise performance doesn't really come into it..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd argue large CSS over large HTML any day. Your CSS will be cached, so your pages will load much faster with smaller HTML. More classes does mean more flexibility, but you'd be surprised at how much you can accomplish using CSS selectors. The only time I see bulking up the HTML as something that is useful is for SEO; see [microformats](http://microformats.org/) for an example of what I mean.

Accuracy should not be a question whatsoever (even if you factor in human error, you should be able to immediately catch your mistake). As far as speed goes, I doubt it has an effect on performance. Keep in mind all the rendering is done client-side so you don't need to worry about the server doing any more work because of more complex CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely agree with Wex re css caching (more css, less html)

As for your question on

> *Is it better limit my HTML to as few of classes and ids as possible and keep the size of the HTML small OR is it better to use a lot
>   nested CSS rules.*

From the rendering performance perspective it's actually more beneficial to use flat (one-level) selectors because of browser engines matching them right-to-left i.e. prefer `.list-item-first` to `ul li:first-child` - this is less manageable from maintanance perspective but results in marginally better performance. At the same time, you'd rarely see a difference in a reasonably sized stylesheet, so it's more a matter of preference.

[More on css rendering performance](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly argue against using a lot of [nesting](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grouping_nesting.asp) with your css.. one problem with css nesting is that it makes your css code a lot less reusable. I recommend you take a look at [this](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) page that explains the concept of **Object Oriented CSS (OOCSS)**, which has this key concept:

“rarely use location-dependent styles”. An object should look the same no matter where you put it. So instead of styling a specific `<h2>` with `.myObject h2 {...}`, create and apply a class that describes the `<h2>` in question, like `<h2 class="category">.*`

To see a more detailed discussion of why using css selectors can be limiting.. see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043976/oocss-separation-of-container-and-content/15044367#15044367).

Comment: Definitely a good suggestion as far as increasing consistency throughout the site.