# css background image not showing in DIV

Tags: css, html, background-image

If I do that:

```
.floatingBox div div {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   background-image: url('../images/car.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

<div class='floatingBox'>
    <div class='effect2'>
        <a href=/Devis/moto><div class='motorbike'></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the background image shows up fine.

However if I do:

```
.floatingBox div div {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

.motorbike {
    background-image: url('../images/moto.png');
}
```

then, the background image does not show up any longer.

How come ?

Comment: Just a guess but isn't the `.motorbike` background overwritten by the top one since it has a more specified path? Try specifying the bottom one, or replacing the background attributes from the top one to the `.motorbike`

Comment: Can You put jsfiddle to help us help You?

Comment: inspect your element on browser. i assume you know how to. and check if your css properties are where you want. at the first look everything seems quite ok. my only question is that if that link with div has some width height. i'm very sure that there are 0px by 0px.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try changing you html to

```
<div class='floatingBox'>
    <div class='effect2'>
        <a href='/Devis/moto' class='motorbike'></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css to

```
.motorbike {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../images/car.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    width: /* put a non-zero width value here */ ;
    height: /* put a non-zero height value here */ ;
}
```

**explanation:** an `<a>` tag can take the place of a `<div>` tag if you set its display property to block.. (`<a>` defaults to `display:inline`)

you also want to set the width and height since there is no content inside that div.

in general its a good idea to **avoid cascading** in your css styles.. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043976/oocss-separation-of-container-and-content/) for a detailed discussion of that

Comment: Or `inline-block` is good if you still want content to flow around it.

Comment: Plus you will need to specify a width and height if you are not going to put content in it but depend on backgrounds instead.

Comment: @abbood, I've tried that but no luck :(  I've noticed the anchor tag's dimensios are 0px * 0px, could it be the reason why the background image is not showing ?

Comment: @user1098555 yeah i just updated the answer.. if there is no content in the div, it will have 0 width and height (that's why a jsfiddle is always a good idea.. css is tricky when it's done in the developer's head ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should not put a div inside a link tag. Put it outside.

Comment: Indeed, you div closing tag is inside anchor tag

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I do that, there will be nothing to click on. Besides, are you sure this is the reason the background image is not showing up ?

Comment: Putting a `div` within an `a` element is perfectly valid HTML5.

Comment: If You will give `a{display: block; height: 50px; width: 50px}` it should help - I have miss type

Comment: what's wrong with putting a div inside a link tag? i do that whenever it's necessary

Comment: @igor Only useful for html5 browsers anyway. still a few oldies out there. Thanks for the spec.

Comment: @fredsbend: Old browsers have always supported this behavior, too.  Apart from that, there is no harm in using documents with `<!DOCTYPE html>` for tag-soup parsing old browsers.

Comment: @igor except it makes for a mess of junk code, imo. I am a firm believer that tag-soup, hacks, et al are unnecessary except for when standards do not yet support a feature. Good to know though. I have never even tried, figuring it would yield bad results.

Comment: @fredsbend: There is no such thing as an “HTML5 browser”. HTML5 is an evolution of HTML4, often acknowledging previously disallowed usage patterns that would be supported nevertheless. The use of block-level elements within <a> is one such example. Furthermore, HTML5 oftentimes just adds on top of HTML4; graceful degradation for older browsers is one of its core design principles. Consequently, there is IMO no reason to _not_ write anything else than HTML5 documents any more.  The only question is how many of its new features can/should be used with regards to browsers that shall be supported.

Answer (score 2):

At the first look it seems that your anchor and link don't have any content so implicit there is 0px width and height.

Comment: correct ! Now using @abbod code and adding some string within the anchor tag, the background image shows up. However it's ugly because 1) I don't want any text to appear and 2) the background image is 150px * 100px, so the container needs to be of that size. Any idea what could be done ?

Comment: force it. put your .motorbike to that size: width:150px and height:100px.

Comment: yes, it dit work. I'll mark abbod's reply as the answer because in the end his code is the one I've been using, and he had added width and height in his answer, which I did not see at first. Thanks a lot for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your div closing tag is inside anchor tag. Second of all, there's no content displaying inside your anchor tag (it's just empty tag, so it doesn't have dimensions etc.), which means exactly like there's no text in your link tag - making it hidden (since there's nothing to display)

Comment: ok, fair enough. I've changed the html to:      <div class='floatingBox'><div class='effect2'><div class='motorbike'><a href=/Devis/moto>test</a></div></div></div>   However, this does not change anything. The background image is not showing up if I set the background path in its own css class. The only difference now is that I have the string 'test' showing in the DIV, which is not what I want. I could use an IMG tag and put it in the anchor tag, that works fine, but I wanted to use the background-image css attribute on a DIV instead. Do you think it's a bad idea ?

Comment: Try adding display: block property