# Can I adhere to OOCSS separation of container and content when object style need to depend on parent container?

Tags: css, css-selectors, oocss

My question is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043976/oocss-separation-of-container-and-content), but it's regarding the same principle, so this quote is relevant here too:

from https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki

> Essentially, this means “rarely use location-dependent styles”. An object should look the same no matter where you put it. So instead of styling a specific h2 with .myObject h2 {...}, create and apply a class that describes the h2 in question, like h2 class="category".

But what if the design dictates that an object's style changes when it's inside certain containers? Here's a simplified example of my problem. Let's say there's an object called foo, and a container object called bar. foo and bar have their own location-independent styles:

```
.foo {
    ...
}
.bar {
    ...
}
```

But when foo is inside container bar like so, its color needs to change when the user hovers over bar:

```
<div class="bar">
    ...
    <div class="foo">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

It seems in this case, you can't avoid writing a location-dependent selector that looks like this:

```
.bar:hover .foo {
    // color style
}
```

One solution I thought of is to introduce a class that's explicitly dependent on bar (named using [BEM naming convention](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/) to be explicit about parent-child relationship), and add it to the foo object:

```
<div class="bar">
    ...
    <div class="foo bar__foo">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>

.bar:hover .bar__foo {
    // color style
}
```

I want to confirm, is this a good way to handle the issue? Are there other ways in OOCSS as well?

Comment: My opinion is, there is nothing on the W3C website that says you should refrain from using `.class1 .class2` for a selector. Things like `+` or `~` or `nth-child` are not advised against either. So just use them. Do not add new classes to your markup just to satisfy some vague rule made up elsewhere, by people who do not understand what the meaning of a class is. In this example, only add a new class if the foo inside the bar does something else than a foo outside the bar.

Answer (score 1):

The big concern here isn't that your chaining classes together, it's that your classes are location independent. Nesting is going to happen. Approaches like OOCSS are great because they help to you know when things like nesting and class-naming is going awry.

**Mark Otto** released a Code Guide last week and [here are some relevant points:](http://mdo.github.io/code-guide/#css-classes)

> - Keep selectors short and strive to limit the number of elements in each selector to three.
> - Scope classes to the closest parent only when necessary (e.g., when not using prefixed classes).

He also provides these examples:

```
/* Bad example */
span { ... }
.page-container #stream .stream-item .tweet .tweet-header .username { ... }
.avatar { ... }

/* Good example */
.avatar { ... }
.tweet-header .username { ... }
.tweet .avatar { ... }
```

In short: **Aim to scope a class to it's parent.** Don't go further than 3 selectors.

You're fine going with:

```
.bar:hover .foo { ... }
```

#### **Further Reading**

- [Stop The Cascade](http://markdotto.com/2012/03/02/stop-the-cascade/)
- [Scope CSS Classes with Prefixes](http://markdotto.com/2012/02/16/scope-css-classes-with-prefixes/)